# How NOT to select columns using select() dplyr when you have character vector of colnames?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to unselect columns in my dataset using dplyr, but I am not able to achieve that since last night.

I am well aware of work around but I am being strictly trying to find answer just through dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c('a','b','c','d'))
df %>% select(-c('x'))
```

Gives me an error : Error in -c("x") : invalid argument to unary operator

Now, I know that select takes in unquoted values but I am not able to sub-select in this fashion.

Please note the above dataset is just an example, we can have many columns.

Thanks,

Prerit

Comment: select(-x) should work

Comment: @Prerit: SO asks you to use the [edit] capabilities and avoid using comments to modify or clarify your questions. (I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: this is in the documentation and in the examples

Comment: @42 done! edited the question

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Edit: OP's actual question was about how to use a character vector to select or deselect columns from a dataframe. Use the `one_of()` helper function for that:

```
colnames(iris)

# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"

cols <- c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length")

select(iris, one_of(cols)) %>% colnames

# [1] "Petal.Length" "Sepal.Length"

select(iris, -one_of(cols)) %>% colnames

# [1] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Width" "Species"
```

You should have a look at the select helpers (type `?select_helpers`) because they're incredibly useful. From the docs:

`starts_with()`: starts with a prefix

`ends_with()`: ends with a prefix

`contains()`: contains a literal string

`matches()`: matches a regular expression

`num_range()`: a numerical range like x01, x02, x03.

`one_of()`: *variables in character vector.*

`everything()`: all variables.

---

Given a dataframe with columns names a:z, use `select` like this:

```
select(-a, -b, -c, -d, -e)

# OR

select(-c(a, b, c, d, e))

# OR

select(-(a:e))

# OR if you want to keep b

select(-a, -(c:e))

# OR a different way to keep b, by just putting it back in

select(-(a:e), b)
```

So if I wanted to omit two of the columns from the `iris` dataset, I could say:

```
colnames(iris)

# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"

select(iris, -c(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% colnames()

# [1] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Width" "Species"
```

But of course, the best and most concise way to achieve that is using one of `select`'s helper functions:

```
select(iris, -ends_with(".Length")) %>% colnames()

# [1] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Width" "Species"
```

P.S. It's weird that you are passing quoted values to `dplyr`, one of its big niceties is that you *don't* have to keep typing out quotes all the time. As you can see, bare values work fine with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`.

Comment: You say that's a "nicety", but I find it incredibly confusing. In regular R you are required to quote column names in everything except formulas, while in the tidyverse quoted column names are not accepted. It's really a different language. (I don't think it's "weird" at all that someone would have tried that. Rather I think it's completely natural.)

Comment: You're totally right, of course. It's not a big deal for me to switch between the two styles (it's obvious to me when the context changes from Tidyverse to base R), but it can be difficult for new people to learn the two paradigms together. That's why I feel it's important to have a working understanding of base R before jumping into Tidyverse, it makes it clear that Tidyverse is the exception to the rule.

Comment: Problem is I know it's weird but, I ended with a character vector and I don't know how to select using select() and I don't want to have those columns in my tibble. If it doesn't work, I'll just solve it using a work around. :)

Comment: main problem is I ended with a character vector, there are other stuff like rlang::expr etc. but that just looks so..errmm weird and unnatural.

Comment: This is the first time you've mentioned a character vector, this is something you should put into your reprex or else the question you're asking is not actually your question...

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to use a character vector of column names to select/deselect columns. Have a look at `select`'s other helper functions, they often come in handy.

Comment: Hello, coming back to my own answer to say that `one_of()` is also VERY useful for writing functions that select columns that _may not be there_. For example, if you want to exclude the `p_value` column if it exists in a dataframe, then use `-one_of("p_value")`.